# object of type 'int' has no len() Python

Tags: python

I have a script to generate random words,

```
import random

letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d","e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"]

def get_random_name(letters, length):
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))

print(get_random_name(1,12))
```

But when I run, I am getting error :

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Please help. Where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 7):

You are passing letters as an int, you need to pass the letters list:

```
print(get_random_name(letters,12))
```

Passing `get_random_name(1,12)` you are trying to call  `random.choice(1)` which will obviously fail